# MySQL select and group where members contain one value but not another

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following structure (called `assets`):

```
isbn       | format
-----------+----------
9111111111 | pdf
9111111111 | mobi
9111111111 | epub
9222222222 | pdf
9333333333 | pdf
9333333333 | epub
```

I want to select all the `ISBN`s that have an `epub` but don't have a `mobi` `format`.

In the example above, the desired result would only contain `9333333333`

`9111111111` has a mobi, so don't return it. `9222222222` has no epub, so don't return it either.

I've tried a combination of `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` but nothing is returning the correct results. This seems like it ought to be simple but for some reason, I'm really struggling to form an idea around it.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT x.* FROM my_table x LEFT JOIN my_table y ON y... = x... AND y.... =... WHERE x.... = ... AND y... IS NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an anti join to achieve this

```
select isbn from assets 
where format = 'epub'
  and not exists (select true from assets b where b.isbn = assets.isbn and b.format = 'mobi')
```

on other database systems this can be done a little more elegantly as

```
select isbn from assets where format = 'epub'
except all
select isbn from assets where format = 'mobi'
```

if I'm pulling just the isbn and the database supports the feature, i prefer the `except` approach. however, if I need to include other fields from the `assets` table, then I would use the anti-join approach as I can just add the column names to the outermost select clause.

Comment: Ooh, the `except all` approach threw an error - `Incorrect usage of EXCEPT and ALL` (could be MariaDB) but the latter example works a charm! Thanks!

Comment: right, i forgot, mysql doesn't support `except`. updating answer.

Comment: @OKsure, it seems mariadb has support except / except all in more recent versions. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/except/. Perhaps you're on an earlier version.

Comment: good spot - yes they added `EXCEPT ALL/DISTINCT` in 10.15.x - the DB is running 10.13.x